# CSS website background

Tags: html, css

I am looking for some info on CSS style used for many websites these days. Its a style where whole screen is occupied by one background and the websites content is posted on top of it under smaller dimensions. 
Something like this website: http://www.obiweb.com.au/ 
        How do we achieve something like this?

Comment: Have you tried viewing the source of that website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily achieved by using the css background property on the body tag:

```
body {background:#fff url(image.png) repeat 0 0}
```

You can read up on this css property here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

You would then have a div container inside your body tag that has a width and margin set to auto:

```
.container {margin:0 auto;width:900px}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

They apply background image to `body` tag. Here is for example CSS  used by the site you mentioned in your question:

```
body {
  background:url("/site/default/images/bg_860.png") repeat-y scroll center center transparent;
}
```

You may read more about `background` property and its uses [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp).